# Am I using Apache Spark as good as possible?

Tags: apache-spark

I am currently studiyng apache spark. I am currently running on a single-node configuration on my local machine.
As practice, I take a JSON file that represents an event stream, and load it into the API using 
`spark.read.json()`

and then, to query them I use 
`spark.sql('some query')`

My goal is to find certain relations between those events.

now, Im aware of other functions called `map()` and `filter()` and so on that can achive the same logic in different ways.
Are these functions simply alternative ways of processing the same data, or are there any deeper differences under the hood?

Answer (score 1):

Using `spark.sql()` and the sql like `DataFrame` api (methods like `.select()`, `.where()`, `.join()`, etc.) are basically the same from a performance and optimization standpoint. Those transformations are ran through the catalyst optimizer to determine the most efficient way to process the underlying data set. Likewise, spark has several [native](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) functions, which can be used by either method, and are optimized by the catalyst engine to perform extremely well.

I personally lean very far towards **avoiding** the `spark.sql()` function simply because it becomes much easier to capture typos and other errors at compile time, rather than at run time. For example:

```
`spark.sql("select name from emps wehre salary > 10000")`
```

will compile without issue, but fail at run-time, while:

```
`emps.wehre($"salary" > 10000).select("name")`
```

will fail at compile time, saving a lot of trouble.

Granted, there is some functionality that is only available (quite rare, tbh) as sql expressions, and in those cases you can utilize the `.expr()` method. This allows you to still get *most* of your query's clauses compile-time checked.

With all of that said, doing transformations with `.map()` should be reserved for highly specialized tasks that cannot be expressed using the normal sql like methods. `.map()` lambdas are not optimized by catalyst, and will not perform as well. Further, using the `.map()` function against a `DataFrame` requires you to interact with each row as a `Row` object which can be somewhat awkward, tedious, and prone to run-time errors.

If you must `.map()`, use a strongly typed `Dataset` to do it, as it's much easier to work with the values in your lambda function. Converting to a `Dataset` is as simple as calling `.as[T]` on it.

Lastly, A middle ground which was not mentioned in the question is utilizing UDFs to do custom work. A UDF is great for being able to apply a function to one or more values within a row. They also are *not* optimized, but they avoid some of the other overhead that `.map()` brings to the table.

A general rule of thumb: if (almost) the *entire row* is required to be the input of your transformation, use a `.map()`. If only 1-3 values within the row are required, then a UDF would be sufficient.

[Further Reading](https://medium.com/@Farox2q/udfs-vs-map-vs-custom-spark-native-functions-91ab2c154b44)